# Object always nil while using ObjectMapper and Alamofire

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

It seems that no matter what I do, my converted JSON variable in Swift is always nil. I'm following the documentation for [AlamofireObjectMapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper) to the letter and nothing seems to be working.

```
func loginAF(username: String, password: String, url: String) {

        Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: ["username": username, "passoword": password]).responseObject { (response: Resultset?, error: NSError?) in
            println(response!)
            println(response?.account?.mongoId)
        }
    }
```

That last print statement is `nil`

Here is the `Resultset` struct, which is what it should be pulling from:

```
struct Resultset: Mappable {
    var account: Account?

    init(){}
    init?(_ map: Map) {
        mapping(map)
    }

    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
        account <- map["account"]
    }
}

struct Account: Mappable {
    var mongoId: Int?

    init() {}
    init?(_ map: Map) {
        mapping(map)
    }

    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
        mongoId <- map["mongoId"]
    }
}
```

I know for sure I'm getting valid data, here's a taste of what it looks like:

```
{"errors":[],"resultset":{"account":{"mongoId":"55a7961fdf5d3ca421ff4cb9"},"locations":[{"......
```

If anyone knows any other way to convert JSON to objects easily, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried resultset.account instead of account as in  account <- map["account"] ->  account <- map["resultset.account"] ?

Answer (score 1):

one of your parameters in the request is called passoword, and secondly which i think is the solution is that you cannot use structs.

> This is due to the fact that Serializer’s are expected to return AnyObject as its result, and structs are not AnyObject, which is a shame since structs are the perfect value types.

I got this from here
http://kaandedeoglu.com/2015/02/20/From%20JSON%20to%20Type-safe%20objects%20in%20Swift/

Additionally in the Documentation I just saw classes.
I hope this helps you

Comment: Changing my struct to a class worked for me. Seems like only an issue when nesting objects.